# How to avoid zooming text in svg

Tags: text, svg, zooming

If I have several lines (blocks, polygons, whatever) spread about the canvas, and I want their stroke-width to remain the same even when I zoom in ...

for example, I have a graph of temperature vs time, and there is a little line on the time axis to mark each hour - so the distance between them increases as I zoom in, but I don't want them to get any thicker ...

Then I can provide an attribute *vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"* for the t-axis object.

But suppose I have several texts ...

for example, every 24th hour has a date written beside it ...

then there seems to be no way to prevent the text from being stretched; i.e. I cannot provide an attribute *text-effect="non-scaling-text"* ...

In my example, I am only zooming in one dimension, and stretched-out text is ugly, and squashed-in text is unreadable.

Is there any workaround for this?

Here are more details, as requested.

I am drawing a graph on a canvas much wider than the viewing area (and which will get even wider if it gets zoomed). Sliders are provided so the viewer can *pan* and *zoom* to inspect any part of it in detail.

So there are two objects *graphobj* which comes from the application data and *tlineobj* which is the time axis, and which consists of a line the length of the canvas, with short vertical lines to mark off the hours and bigger ones to mark the start of each day. So each time the viewer alters a slider it obeys something like

`tlineobj.setAttribute("transform", 'translate('+someamount+',0), 'scale('+someamount+',1)')`

ans similarly for `graphobj`.
So I am stretching it out horizontally, but not vertically.

Now `tlineobj` is constructed by a Javascript routine. For simplicity, forget about names of days and months, and let us just write *daynos* in the proper places. So I write a function like:

```
Function doDate(i) {
    dayno = some_model.cloneNode(false)
    dayno.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i))
    dayno.setAttribute("x", i*some_factor)
    tlineobj.appendChild(dayno)
}
```

But now when the `tlineobj` gets zoomed, not only does the distance between the `dayno`s get increased (which is what we want), but each `dayno` itself gets stretched out, because there is no way to tell the SVG zooming machanism not to do this (although there **is** such a mechanism to do it for vector objects).

The only way I can see to do it is to cause the whole of the `tlineobj` to be regenerated from scratch each time the graph is re-zoomed, and that seems a very kludgy way to so it (or I could go though all the `dayno` objects and change some attribute within them, but that is just as bad).

Comment: I think this is a good question, but I think it would be useful to have some example code/markup for people to play with. Possibly strokewidth = strokewidth / zoomfactor type thing ?

Comment: Without seeing any sample code it's hard to say but one approach could be outlining the text and stroke if it doesnt need to be dynamic.

Comment: It's hard to provide example code when you don't know what code to write :-(. But I can provide a little more information about my setup, so I have extended the question accordingly.